# Gmail new via feature causes automatic email from my server to go to the SPAM folder

Tags: email, gmail, spam

I used to send automatic email to users of my website for various reasons like

- activating new user accounts
- when their question on a forum gets an answer
- etc

However, now with the new gmail via feature, my emails go to their spam folder as it has (info@bamozir.com via blabla.hostgator.com)

I removed the email content to make sure the problem is not because of the content of the activation email, it still goes to the spam folder.